# Creating a Hash Map of objects of a class

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to create a hash map of objects of a class.

The class is as follows -

```
public class BitbucketRecordDataModel {
    private String softwareId;
    private String scmUrl;
    private String aggregationDate;

    public BitbucketRecordDataModel(String softwareId, String scmUrl, String aggregationDate) {
        this.softwareId = softwareId;
        this.scmUrl = scmUrl;
        this.aggregationDate = aggregationDate;
    }

    public String getSoftwareId() {
        return softwareId;
    }

    public void setSoftwareId(String softwareId) {
        this.softwareId = softwareId;
    }

    public String getScmUrl() {
        return scmUrl;
    }

    public void setScmUrl(String scmUrl) {
        this.scmUrl = scmUrl;
    }

    public String getAggregationDate() {
        return aggregationDate;
    }

    public void setAggregationDate(String aggregationDate) {
        this.aggregationDate = aggregationDate;
    }
}
```

I am creating a Hash map having key as String and trying to insert values into the hash map. But when I try to retrieve the details of the hash map, I get null and some very weird values which is the name of my class.

```
HashMap<String, BitbucketRecordDataModel> map = new HashMap<String, BitbucketRecordDataModel>();

cacheCondition = "hi";
username = "hi1";
protocol = "hi2";

BitbucketRecordDataModel bitbucketRecordDataModel = new BitbucketRecordDataModel(cacheCondition, username, protocol);

map.put(repoName, bitbucketRecordDataModel);

System.out.println(map.get("deployment-service-api.git"));
```

I am very new to Java and Hash Maps. What am I doing wrong and why I am getting such weird values?

Comment: Try doing `map.get(repoName);` and check the result

Comment: `some very weird values which is the name of my class` - you have to override `toString()` if you want to get not weird values.

Comment: @Eran, Hey that worked a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should override ***toString()*** method of Class. If you don't override it and call from any object instance, it responses as implementation of **Object class**. You can find the basic implementation of it here [please find toString() Method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Object.java)

Please copy shared code block for toString() method below and paste it in the class.

Also i noticed that you define *repoName* as key while putting data to map but you use *deployment-service-api.git* as a key while retrieving the data.

**Please be sure use the same key value.**

```
 @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BitbucketRecordDataModel{" +
                    "softwareId='" + softwareId + '\'' +
                    ", scmUrl='" + scmUrl + '\'' +
                    ", aggregationDate='" + aggregationDate + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
```